# Paste SVG and other formats from clipboard on Mac

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I know I can get PNG data from the clipboard on Mac like this:

```
osascript -e "get the clipboard as «class PNGf»"
```

Is it possible to get other types of data like for example SVG?

Comment: I don't think that svg is a type as it's not native to the mac (at least not my old machine). If you can open and view it in Preview as an svg then that may have changed. But try this: Open a png in preview; select all, copy. Then run an applescript with just `clipboard info` (or `osascript -e 'clipboard info'`). You can try the same after copying the contents of an svg from within whatever app can display it as an svg. When I try, I get a range of types beginning with `«class PDF »` and `TIFF picture`. General Info in Preview classifies it as a PDF.

Comment: SVG files are (XML) text, so it will just be a regular string. For an actual image it would depend on the particular application handling the data.